# Get names of paths used by FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I have a FileProvider set up in my manifest:

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and a file_paths.xml as follows:

```
<paths>
   <external-path
      name="my-external"
      path="." />
   <cache-path
      name="my-cache"
      path="." />
</paths>
```

I want to then determine whether a Uri is one of these paths. So for example, `content://my-cache/blah.jpg` is therefore in the cache-path.

Of course, I can do this simply by comparing against a hard-coded string, "my-cache", but is there a way to programmatically obtain the contents of `file_paths.xml` above?

Comment: You can use `getResources().getXml()` to be able to read in the XML represented by that resource, if that's what you mean. Last I checked, `FileProvider` itself does not expose an API for getting at its copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. I was hoping not to have to read the XML but perhaps I'll just have to! ...or just hard-code the string ;)